# Remove 8 bit from the end of an IPv4 address

Tags: ip-address, bit, ipv4

When I delete 8 bit from the end of an IPv4 address, how many octets remain?

x.x. or x.x.x. ?

Or will the length of the remaining string depend on the address class?

Comment: Octet means 8 bits, so "deleting 8 bits" cannot mean other than "deleting 1 octet".    But an IPv4 address is exactly 32 bits, so it's unclear what your purpose in "deleting 8 bits" really is.

Comment: @dave-not-cutler That is done in the EU to anonymize ip addresses in accordance with the GDPR to turn personal data into non-personal data. Lawyers suggest deleting the last 16 bits. My logfiles show ip addresses as 123.456.789.0, and I wanted to understand if the last 8 or 16 bits have been replaced with that zero.

Comment: An IPv4 address of 123.456.789.0 is very definitely anonymized :-)

Comment: If only the last octet is zero then they've clearly only zeroed 8 bits. But in general you can't be sure: if you see xx.yy.0.0, the 3rd octet could be a 'real zero' or a 'masked zero'.